# Find a CFG for all words that can be obtained in the form $a^ib^{i+k}a^k$

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

Find a CFG for all words that can be obtained in the form of $a^ib^{i+k}a^k$ where $i,k\ge1$.

This is what I have so far:

$$ S\to aXa \\X\to bXB \mid bb  $$

I understand that number of b's must be equal to the addition of the a's on their left and right side.

How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing as $a^ib^ib^ka^k$ makes the rules obvious:
$$S\to XY,X\to aXb|ab,Y\to bYa|ba$$

Comment: @markvs As I understand the question the indices are constrained to start from $1$ (I had included $0$ at first, but then saw the $1,2,3\dots$ up there shortly after clicking post).

Comment: That was an error on my part. I must have said i, j, k = 1, 2, 3.... I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! It is very helpful!